# I want to connect my MongoDB docker to my host pc

Tags: mongodb, docker

I want to connect my MongoDB docker with my program in my host.

I try this:

```
docker pull mongo
docker run -d --name mongodb -p 21017:21017 mongo
docker exec -it mongodb bash
```

All start fine but I couldn't connect to my host, I try to change my archive /etc/mongod.conf but with anything result.
I have a python program in my host and I want to use docker MongoDB and connect both.
[docker container ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjH1x.png)
Thank you very much.

[image: telnet]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use below host & port in your python program which resides on docker host -

```
DB_HOST = localhost
DB_PORT = 27017
```

From your Docker host, mongoDB container should be accessible at `localhost: 27017`

Update 1(as suggested by @Schwarz54) -

Also, you are using wrong mongo port, it should be `27017`.

Run your container using below command -

`docker run -d --name mongodb -p 27017:27017 mongo`

Comment: But localhost its my IP host or my IP container or the IP bridge made by docker. Thak you very much for the help.

Comment: It's IP host. You bind the port to the host as well `-p 21017:21017`. This means mongoDB is accessible on your DockerHost:21017.

Comment: Ok i will try that. Thank you.

Comment: I try that but still getting connect my host IP its 192.168.10.170, my docker container mongo db IP its 172.17.0.2 and the virtual host made by docker bridge mode its 10.0.75.2

Comment: Try to connect on `192.168.10.170:21017`, it should work.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same but nothing I can't connect to the container.

Comment: Share the error. Share output of `telnet 192.168.10.170 21017`. It could be an issue with the firewall.

Comment: I deactivate the firewall but still the problem

Comment: Seems like you have used the wrong port number. Check my updated answer.

Comment: if i open web brower and i write http://192.168.10.170:55059/ the answer its It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port. but whith my python i cant get the connection

Answer (score 2):

That isnt the mongo port `21017`:

Mongo port is `27017` .

Comment: So its okay now? You can connecto to mongo docker with your app?

Comment: if i open web brower and i write http://192.168.10.170:55059/ the answer its It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port. but whith my python i cant get the connection

Comment: A sample of a URI connection to mongo is: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/yourDatabaseName' try with this. If you can post the script when you connect to database will be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem, it was that in my python program I don't remember to import mongo.
Yes, that was the problem.
Now I can:

```py
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.10.170:55059")
```

And all fine.
Thank you for the help I stay two days checking all the code but I don't remember to see if I import the library...